# Is it possible to call do files from a tcl script in modelsim?

Tags: tcl, modelsim

I tried to write an automatic script for modelsim, where I would go through each possible malfunction in the circuit one by one, and then analyze it. For one malfunction, I did everything, and it works, however when I tried to make a loop where I did the same with everyone one by one, I had several problems at once.

1. Can `do` files be called from tcl scripts? Since the actions for one malfunction are performed using the `do` file, and the loop for iterating over them is already a Tcl script.
2. When trying to run the whole thing, modelsim gave an execution result of 0 and that's all, despite the fact that it did not swear at syntax errors.

Here is the do file for one fault (`fault.do`):

```
vmap work work
vcom -reportprogress 300 -work work {sheme.vhd}
vcom -reportprogress 300 -work work {testbench.vhd}
vsim -wav simwave.wlf work.device_tb
env sim:/device_tb/uut
view signals
.signals.tree write signalfile.txt
add wave sim:/device_tb/uut/*
add list sim:/device_tb/uut/*
run  5000 ns
quit -sim

quietly WaveActivateNextPane  {} 0 
dataset open ./simwave.wlf simwave
add wave simwave:/device_tb/uut/*
add list simwave:/device_tb/uut/*
vsim work.device_tb
env sim:/device_tb/uut
view signals
quietly WaveActivateNextPane 
add wave sim:/device_tb/uut/*
add list sim:/device_tb/uut/*
source forc.tcl
tosignal 1
quietly WaveActivateNextPane 

compare start simwave sim
compare options -track
compare add -wave -recursive -tolL {0 ns} -tolT {0 ns} simwave:/device_tb/uut sim:/device_tb/uut
compare add -list -recursive -tolL {0 ns} -tolT {0 ns} simwave:/device_tb/uut sim:/device_tb/uut
compare run
view wave
view list
compare info -write C:/Modeltech_5.7f/examples/dip/compare.txt
source analys.tcl
comp 2
```

And here are my attempts to make a loop for all such faults:

```
set fp [open "signalfile.txt" r]
set cnts 0
set cntoth 0
while { [gets $fp data] >= 0 } {
    if {[string match $data s?] == 1} {
    incr cnts } else {
    incr cntoth }
}

for {set i 0} {$i < $cnts} {incr i} {
    set var $env($i)
    source fault.do
    exec $var }

set fn [open "errors.txt" r]
set er 0
while { [gets $fn data] >= 0 } {
    incr er }
set per [expr $er/[expr $cntoth + $cnts]]
puts $per
```

Can anyone suggest how best to implement this? I'll be very thankful)

Comment: As far as I'm aware (as someone who doesn't use Modelsim _at all)_ you can just `source` that `do` file. It _looks_ like a Tcl script so it probably is one.  The second problem is absolutely the main one here.